# The results of `requests` returning different results when run on gcp cloud

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, cloud

I am trying to scrape some data from this [website](https://www.autotrader.com/car-values/).

I can make successful requests on my local machine. Here is my code:

```
import requests

base = 'https://www.autotrader.com/car-values/'

headers = {}  # My headers go here

r = requests.get(base, headers=headers)
soup = str(r.content)

if 'engineers' in soup:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

The if else block checks if the request returned the expected results because when it doesn't, the website says 'please contact our engineers'. That's what I am checking for.

But if I run this same script on VM instance of GCP, I am getting `True` which basically means the result is not what I wanted.

I also printed out the response headers by running the script both locally and on GCP and they don't match. How can I make the script run as expected?

This is just a test script but the main scraper should run for 2-3 days, that's why I need to use GCP.

Please help....

Comment: Seems like your IP is blacklisted.

Comment: How? Will there be a different IP when I make the request through GCP servers?